# iOS MetalPerformanceShader: How to access the raw texture data inside MPSImage

Tags: ios, gpu, metal

I would like to write some GPU accelerated functions for iOS Metal MPSImage. The first thing I need to know is how to access the raw texture data inside MPSImage. When the featureChannel > 4, there are multiple slices of texture data. I am not sure how to access each of these slices.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In typical usage, the data is stored in sets of four feature channels, which I will call a quartet. A MTLTexture would call these a texel and might imagine that they are r,g,b,a, but really these are feature_channels[ some_offset + {0,1,2,3}]

MPSImages are usually MTLTexture2DArrays. The first quartet for pixel[0,0] (feature channels 0-3) appears at coordinate {0,0} in image slice 0.  The second quartet (feature channels 4-7) for pixel[0,0] appears at coordinate {0,0} in image slice 1, and so forth.

```
// loads the set of 4 contiguous aligned feature channels containing channel
float4 loadQuartet( texture2d_array<float, access::sample> src, 
                    uint2 position, 
                    ushort channel )
{
   return src.read( position, firstChannel >> 2 ); 
}
```